# add a border (filled with 0's) around an existing array

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast

I'm trying to add a border (filled with 0's) around an existing array.
My code:

```
a = np.random.random((4, 5))
m, n = a.shape
b = np.zeros((m+1, n+1))
b[1:-1,1:-1] = a
a,b
```

but I got a error:
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,5) into shape (3,4)`

Why can't I directly assign values to parts of a 2D numpy array? where is the problem？

Comment: You want a border on each side, so the new shape must be `(m+2, n+2)`.

Comment: You can assign values, if you get the sizes right.

Comment: Great! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish your task using *np.pad* function:

```
b = np.pad(a, 1)
```

Shorter code than yours.

Read the documentation of this function for any details.

Comment: fantastic! Many thanks!

Comment: So now you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
b[:, [0, -1]] = 0
b[[0, -1], :] = 0
```

Comment: That would be great if you add some explanation this is not about the question only its about rest of the community how other users are supposed to understand above lines of code?